# Total curvature

Tags: differential-geometry

> Compute the total curvature of the the unit sphere $S^2$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, that is compute $\int_{S^2}K(p)dA$ where $K(p)$ is the Gauss Curvature.

Given the metric:
$$G = [g_{ij}] = \pmatrix{ x_u \dot\ x_u & x_u \dot\ x_v \\ x_u \dot\ x_v & x_v \dot\ x_v \\}$$

and the stereographic coordinates given by the spherical metric:
$$g_{uu} = g_{vv} = \frac{4}{(1+u^2 + v^2)^2},\ \ g_{uv}=0\implies \frac{4}{(1+u^2+v^2)^2}\pmatrix{ 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\}$$
then I can find the Gaussian curvature $(K)$ of the spherical metric by Gauss's remarkable theorem:

$$ K = -\frac{1}{2\sqrt{g_{11}g_{22}}} \left( \left( \frac{g_{11_{v}}}{\sqrt{g_{11}g_{22}}}\right)_v + \left( \frac{g_{22_{u}}}{\sqrt{g_{11}g_{22}}}\right)_u \right).$$

I got the Gaussian curvature $K(p)  = 1$.

Then $\int_{S^2}1 \dot\ dA = \int_{S^2} dA = \int_{S^2} dudv.$ But, unfortunately, I forgot how to integrate $\int_{S^2} dudv$ (it's been awhile since I worked with them).

I know $\int_{S^2} dudv = 4\pi$ but can anyone show me how?

Comment: Can you write down the metric with respect to the stereographic projection? How about $dA$, what does it look like in the local coordinate?

Comment: @John Is the first fundamental form in stereographic coordinates given by the spherical metric $$ \frac{4}{(1+u^2+v^2)^2}\pmatrix{ 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\}?$$ Or am I wrong?

Comment: You are right. How about $dA$?

Comment: Personally, I would prefer to do the calculations in spherical coordinates, but, of course, you can do it by stereographic projection. Yes, @Lays, I believe that's the right formula for the metric.

Comment: @TedShifrin What is the difference between stereographic projection and coordinates?

Comment: I mean parametrization in spherical coordinates: $x(u,v)=(\sin u\cos v,\sin u\sin v,\cos u)$, $0<u<\pi$, $0<v<2\pi$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Gotcha.

Comment: @Lays: $dA$ is the "area" element. In Euclidean space it is just $dxdy$. In general, one consider two vectors $\frac{\partial}{\partial u}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial v}$ and $dA = |\frac{\partial}{\partial u} \times \frac{\partial}{\partial u}| du dv$. Note that the cross product measure the area of the parallelogram spans by that two vectors, so $dA$ is "infinitesimal" area of the surface.

Comment: @John How do I compute the Gauss curvature of the spherical metric I wrote above? I know the Gauss curvature can be defined as the product of the two principal curvatures which I know how to do. And I know I must calculate all the Christoffel symbols but I don't know how to compute it in the form $$\frac{4}{(1+u^2+v^2)^2}\pmatrix{ 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\}?$$ I only seen examples of calculating Christoffel symbols through a parametrization but not any examples of that form.

Comment: @Lays: You can find it here:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christoffel_symbols

Comment: @John Thanks! I'll check it out.

Comment: @Lays: Note that $dA \neq dudv$.

Comment: @John Hmm, I thought you said "it is just $dxdy$"? What does $dA$ equal?

Comment: That's the case when you have flat metric.

Comment: @John Oh okay, since this is in $S^2$ what will it equal?

Comment: It's given in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the last question, first note that $dA \neq dudv$. Indeed, using local coordinate given by stereographic projection,

$$g_{uu} = g_{vv} = \frac{4}{(1+u^2 + v^2)^2},\ \ g_{uv}=0$$

thus $dA = \sqrt{\det g_{ij}} dudv = \frac{4dudv}{(1+u^2 + v^2)^2}dudv$. Thus

$$\int_{\mathbb S^2} dA = \int_{\mathbb R^2} \frac{4}{(1+u^2 + v^2)^2}dudv = ?$$

Comment: Just to make sure I understand exactly what is going on where does $dA$ come from? Is it defined to be $dA = \sqrt{\det g_{ij}} dudv$ in spherical coordinates? Will it be different in hyperbolic metric?

Comment: It is defined by the above expression. It is invariant in any coordinate system and if $g_{ij}$ is $\delta_{ij}$ (Euclidean metric), then it reduces to $dudv$.

Comment: Gotcha and for $\int_{\mathbb S^2} dA = \int_{\mathbb R^2} \frac{4}{(1+u^2 + v^2)^2}dudv = ...,$ I forgot hot to integrate double integrals. How will I solve that?

Comment: hint: change to spherical coordinate.

Comment: Understand, I must review multivariable calculus again. Thank you very much for all your help, John!

Comment: @Lays: I hope you enjoyed the question, that's the question that every one learning differential geometry has to answer once.

Comment: Yes I did. Differential Geometry is probably, so far, my favorite math class I have taken.

Comment: Oh, I am glad you said that! Indeed, I am working in differential geometry.

Comment: Awesome! Can you recommend me some books I can read? Its hard to get a great grasp on differential geometry during the semester so I was going to re-learn it during the winter break. I've been recommended so far the books "flatland" and "the shape of space". Are there others you can recommend me?

Comment: Which books are you using for the moment?

Comment: We aren't using any particular book. We are using my professor's class notes and Ted Shifrin (above us) online lecture notes as a reference.

Comment: Ted Shifrin's note seems to be very good, and not so easy for a first course (especially in later chapter). However, except Gauss Bonnet theorem, it seems that it doesnt has other "global result". You can find some in DoCarmo's "Differential geometry of curves and surfaces". This one is more advanced than that lecture notes and is a classic.